# ViewState handler updateLayout method never get hit when handled within default.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, viewstate, winjs

I am starting with a blank template where I get a default.htm and default.js. I want to handle the event when app goes from full to snap or filled mode etc. I have added updateLayout method but when I add a breakpoint here, its never get hit. The break point on ready method is getting hit. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// For an introduction to the Page Control template, see the following documentation:  
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232511  
(function () {  
    "use strict";  
    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("default.html", {  
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It  
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.  
        ready: function (element, options) {  

        },

        unload: function () {
            // TODO: Respond to navigations away from this page.
        },

        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {

        }
    });


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but `updateLayout` isn't actually an event handler.

The navigation framework, which is included when starting from other templates, handles a different event (`window.onresize`), and calls the updateLayout function if it exists.  If you create a new project using the Navigation template, for example, and inspect navigator.js, you will see where the `onresize` event is handled, and the `updateLayout` function is called.

If you start from the Blank template, this functionality is not in place, so you would either need to (a) handle the `onresize` event, (b) add navigator.js to your project, or (c) use a different project template.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Within onresize how can I know what viewState app has. For example if I put my app from fullLandsace to snap, how can I get this value within onresize event?

Comment: You can check the value of `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value` and it will have a value like `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped`.  However with Windows 8.1 forward, it is recommended to instead check for specific widths since the user can have multiple "snapped" apps at once.  For example, you might check `document.documentElement.offsetWidth < 500`.